# Feature module not exporting component

Tags: angular, typescript, import, module

My simple app has a root module named *AppModule* and a feature module named *HomeModule*. I'm trying to create a route for a component named *HomeComponent* (which is part of *HomeModule*) but all I get is

```
Module "HomeModule" has no exported member 'HomeComponent'
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { HomeComponent } from './Home/home.module.ts' // HomeComponent not found

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { HomeComponent }  from './home.component.ts';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
  exports:      [ HomeComponent ]
})

export class HomeModule { }
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>'
})

export class HomeComponent { }
```

Why is *HomeModule* not exporting its component?

Comment: Does my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ref1:http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html
Ref2:https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#imports

## Issue 1: NgModel Import/Export

```
import { HomeComponent } from './Home/home.module.ts' // HomeComponent not found
```

home.module.ts exports `HomeModule`, not `HomeComponent`.

@NgModule exports make Angular2 *features* of those export components available to the importing module. *features* can be template directives, selector, injectable service, etc.

Home component *feature* is its selector. So importing `HomeModule` into app.module will make `HomeComponent` selector `home` available to any app.module's component.

To have HomeModule export HomeComponent explictly, index.js and index.d.ts are needed. (Inspired by Fabio Antunes answer)

### Use selector `home`

To use this, `exports: [ HomeComponent ]` is required in home.module.ts.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeModule } from './Home/home.module';

import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HomeModule,
        routing],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts** using selector `home`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <home></home>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'APP';
}
```

### Use HomeComponent

To use HomeComponent directly, we need to add index.js and index.d.ts into ./Home

**./Home/index.js**

```
exports.HomeModule = require('./home.module').HomeModule;
exports.HomeComponent = require('./home.component').HomeComponent;
```

**./Home/index.d.ts**

```
exports * './home.module';
exports * from './home.component';
```

Then import Home Module like npm package

**app.routing.ts**

```
// We are importing the module directory, not ./Home/home.module.ts
import { HomeComponent } from './Home';

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

## Issue 2: Routing (to child module)

To route to a module, the child module need to have its own router setup.

Use `loadChildren` in parent routing(app.routing.ts).

Use `RouterModule.forChild` in child routing(home.routing.ts).

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeModule } from './Home/home.module';

import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HomeModule,
        routing],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <nav>
      <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'APP';
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './Home/home.module'
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**Home/home.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { HomeComponent }  from './home.component';

import { routing } from './home.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent]
})

export class HomeModule { }
```

**Home/home.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const homeRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes);
```

Comment: For a moment I figured that defining `path: 'home', loadChildren: './Home/home.module'` along with the child routing `path: 'home', component: HomeComponent` would yield URLs like `example.com/home/home`, but apparently not. Even more, when NOT repeating the `home` path in `Home/home.routing.ts`, then requesting `example.com/home` fails. (Just for future readers; I'm sure you know, @John.)

Answer (score 3):

Feature modules should import CommonModule instead of BrowserModule

Answer (score 1):

When setting up a route where your `app.route.ts` will load your HomeModule using `loadChildren` there are two things you must do. Either:

```
export default class HomeModule() {} // note *default*
```

or in your `app.route.ts` you need to add `#HomeModule`:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './Home/home.module#HomeModule' <-- or like this
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

If you plan to add additional routes to the home.route.ts it might be a good idea to define `children` property like:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const homeRoutes: Routes = [
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: "",
            component: HomeComponent
        },
        {
            path: ":id",
            component: HomeDetailsComponent"
        }
    ]
]
```

What you have to remember in the above case is that your main `RouterOutlet` in your app.component.ts (if it is called like that), is **not going to serve** the route such as `http://some_url/Home/1` in order to load HomeDetailsComponent.

The thing is that the route served by `HomeDetailsComponent` is a child route of `HomeComponent` and as such HomeComponent's `template` or `templateUrl` must have it's own `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` defined, othwerise you will get an error message `Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeDetailsComponent'.`

Answer (score 1):

@yourfriendzak, just remove the '.ts' from below statement:

```
import { HomeComponent } from './Home/home.module.ts' // HomeComponent not found
```

Hope it helps...